# Play Framework run job after all other jobs

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I want to run a job after all other jobs have executed. Do anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: The question is poorly written.
What is a "job", who executes it? Background story? 

We are not mind readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a database counter for this. Update the counter every time a job completes (might want to handle case of job failure too) and have your job running with @Every annotation and polling for that counter.

When the counter reaches the total number of jobs then execute your dependant job.

Answer (score 2):

"The simple way is to use only one Job
annotated with @OnApplicationStart that schedules other tasks..."

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/teNk2W_0o-E%5B1-25%5D